# Display Image on Mouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mouseover

How do I display an image on mouse over? I also need to underline the text next to the image on mouse over? On mouseout I have to hide the image and make the text normal again.

This is my html field

```
<img src="img.jpg"> Name
```

Now when I load the page I want not to display the image unless I have the mouse over the place it should appear.

Comment: Please show some code

Answer (score 6):

**CSS**

```
#test{
    display:none
}
```

**HTML**

```
<img id="test" src="img.jpg"/> <span>Name</span>
```

**jQuery**

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
   $('span').on('mouseenter', function () {
       $('#test').show();
       $(this).css({
           "text-decoration": "underline"
       });
   }).on('mouseleave', function () {
       $('#test').hide();
       $(this).css({
           "text-decoration": ''
       });
   });;
```

});

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Vgj8q/2/)

**Documentation**

[jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/)

[document.ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

[jquery.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

[jQuery.show()](http://api.jquery.com/show/)

[jQuery.hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)

[jQuery.mouseenter](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/)

[jQuery.mouseleave](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/)

Answer (score 4):

You can do it the below way using the [hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) event.

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('span').hover(function(){
        $(this).addClass('underline'); //to make text underlined on hover
        $('#image').show(); //displays image on mouse in
    },function(){
        $(this).removeClass('underline'); //remove underline on mouse out
        $('#image').hide(); //hides image on mouse out
    });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<img class="hidden" id="image" src="img.jpg"/> <span>Name</span>
```

**CSS:**

```
.hidden{
    display: none;
}
.underline{
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/Vwtn4/)

Comment: The image isn't shown when using your code :/ When I hover over the `<span>` the element gets underlined and the class changes to ***underlined*** but the image doesn't show up

Comment: @IbrahimApachi: That's probably because of jQuery version and the image not being there. Please try [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vwtn4/69/).

Comment: Hm my JQuery version is 2.1.4 and my image should be loaded.. But since your fiddle is working the fault must be on my side. Thank you for the fast response!

Comment: I am sorry for this hassle @Harry. I just changed the class of the image to *foo* and the class in the css as well. It seems like it has some problems when interacting with bootstrap hidden class! Now it works :) In addition I would be very interested how to make the font of the span still stay in the same place instead of getting "crowded out" by the image

Comment: I mean something like [this](http://www.hearthpwn.com/decks/347793-legend-of-the-warsong-commander). Just hover over the colourful text passages like for instance the word *Sunfury Protector* in the text. An image is shown but text doesn't move because of it

Comment: @IbrahimApachi: They are most likely using `position: absolute` for the `img` like in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vwtn4/70/). Hope it helps :)

Comment: Wow that actually did it :D I wish I could upvote your answer twice :P Thank you very much @Harry. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

As answered by Anton, you can use this one as well.

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
   $('span').hover(
    function () {
        alert("1");
        $('#test').show();
    },
    function () {
        alert("2");
        $('#test').hide();
    }
   )
});
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Vgj8q/1/ I have put alert just for reference check that it works.

Comment: I dont know how to do that. I tried it but was not successful. Can you please guide me?

Comment: If that was "answered by Anton", why post another answer?

Comment: @phresnel, I did that because that time I didn't know how to insert fiddle link in my answer itself. So I commented it to my answer. And moreover, I don't prefer taking someone else's credits.

Answer (score 0):

Jquery:-

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $("#textDiv").mouseover(function(){
    $("#imageDiv").hide();
   });

   $("#textDiv").mouseout(function(){
    $("#imageDiv").show();
   });
    });
```

HTML:-

```
    <div id="textImage">
       <div id="imageDiv" style="float:left;">
          <img src="../images/login_background.png"></img>
       </div>
       <div id="textDiv"style="float:left;">
          <a href="#">Name</a>
       </div>
</div>
```

CSS:-

```
    #textImage a {text-decoration:none;}
    #textImage a:hover {text-decoration:underline;}
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <title>Test</title> 
  <script type='text/javascript' src='http://identify.site88.net/jquery-1.9.1.js'></script>
  <style type='text/css'>
       #test{
        display:none
    }
  </style>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
  $(window).load(function(){
  $(document).ready(function () {
       $('span').on('mouseenter', function () {
           $('#test').show();
           $(this).css({
               "text-decoration": "underline"
           });
       }).on('mouseleave', function () {
           $('#test').hide();
           $(this).css({
               "text-decoration": ''
           });
       });;
    });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
    <img id="test" src="http://www.shop.hidra.com.tr/wp-content/uploads/image_1306_1.jpg"/> <span>Name</span>
</body>
</html>
```